# Docker For Mac / Lando: cannot cURL external webservice

Tags: macos, docker, networking

I am testing out [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando) for a new local dev setup.

Everything has gone well so far but I am running into an error that I don't get on my old Vagrant/VM environment, but do with [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando).

We have part of the site that uses Guzzle to fetch data from a web service. On [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando), I get a cURL error:

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to webservice.internalsite.com port 80: No route to host
```

How can I resolve this? When I try to ping that url, it says "Destination host unreachable". I am using Docker For Mac if that factors in.

Comment: how are you running the image? is ithe docker connected to bridge/host/overlay network?

Comment: Hmm I’d have to see. `lando start` brings it all up. This is more or less my first time using Docker.

Comment: Any news on this one? Just ran into the same situation. :-(

Comment: This was because the external service IP was the same as one of the docker containers - it is a web service on our internal network. The fix for me was defining a network in the docker-compose file and changing the subnet to something higher so they would not conflict. It worked.

Comment: Thanks! I also solved mine, it was a different situation, had to make sure the docker container with the web service I wanted to access was connected to the bridge network of the container I wanted to access the web service from.